# Allow 1 day booking with bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have been working with bootstrap-datepicker with little luck. I have the following code but wish to allow a 1 day booking (i.e. picker1 - From date 01/01/15 and picker 2 - To date 01/01/15. At the moment it only allows me to pick the next day for the To date after selecting the initial From date.

At the moment a 1 day booking is classed as 24 hours, over 2 dates (i.e. From 01/01/15 - 02/01/15) would be classed as a 1 day booking and charged at the 1 day rate.

How do I edit the code below or the Javascripts for Bootstrap-Datepicker to allow 1 day bookings to have the same to and from dates? and if the from date is the next day (i.e. 01/01/15 - 02/01/15) charge at a 2 day rate?

```
 var hire_from = null;
    var hire_to = null;

    var setPrice = function () {
        var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
        if (hire_from && hire_to) {
            var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((hire_from - hire_to)/(oneDay)));
            var price = diffDays*$("#enquiry_price").val();
            $("span#weekly_price").html("&pound; "+price.toFixed(0))
            var fee = price*$("#enquiry_discount").val()
            $("span#commission").html(fee.toFixed(0));
        }
    }


var initDatepickers = function(picker1, picker2){

            if($(picker1)[0] && $(picker2)[0]){
                var nowTemp = new Date();
                var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

                var checkin = $(picker1).datepicker({
                  onRender: function(date) {
                    return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
                  },
                  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
                }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
                  var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
                  newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate());
                  checkout.setValue(newDate);
                  hire_from = newDate;
                  setPrice();
                  $.post('/enquiries/presave', {'hire_from': $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', hire_from), authenticity_token: window._token}, function(data){}, 'json');
                  checkin.hide();
                  $(picker2)[0].focus();
                }).data('datepicker');

                var checkout = $(picker2).datepicker({
                    onRender: function(date) {
                        return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
                    }, format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
                }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
                  checkout.hide();
                  var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
                  hire_to = newDate;
                  $.post('/enquiries/presave', {'hire_to': $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', hire_to), authenticity_token: window._token}, function(data){}, 'json');
                  setPrice();
                }).data('datepicker');
            }
        };
```

Thank you for your input and help.

Comment: Looks like you must to change the server side logic. There don't see to be any domain constrain in the javascript code.

Comment: Also I will expect `$.post(...` to be asynchronous, does `setPrice` need the return value of that post somehow?

Comment: Exactly which datepicker are you using? There are a few versions of bootstrap-datepicker. But the code $.datepicker.formatDate looks like the jQueryUI datepicker utility method. Did you write all this code, or are you trying to combine bits and pieces you've found on the web; not a bad thing! just wondering - you might be running into issues with code designed for jqueryui being used with a bootstrap widget.

Comment: @sifriday using code put together for me by a developer. I'm currently useless with all things Javascript and jQuery, so I'm trying to work it all out as I go! Thanks for the thoughts.

Comment: good luck :-) Do you know how to get at your JS console to look for errors? If I am right, you will see an error message like 'Cannot read property 'formatDate' of undefined' This is unlikely to be part of the problem you're trying to solve, but it might mean you're sending bad data to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the picker2 onRender() to:

```
return date.valueOf() < checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
```

to enable the second datepicker to accept the same day.

Then use:

```
var diffDays = Math.ceil(Math.abs((hire_to - hire_from + 1) /(oneDay)));
```

to make the same day checkout be counted as a day's charge, and the next day checkout as 2 days

Comment: Nick you are spot on with the first piece of code you have sent across, so thanks a lot for that. Unfortunately the second piece of code has not worked, I'm trying to work out why. The price just comes up as £0.

Comment: My bad, if both dates are the same, then (hire_from - hire_to) will be 0, and the whole expression would be 0. You probably want hire_to to always be at least one millisecond after hire_from so that the ceil() function will work. So var diffDays = Math.ceil(Math.abs((hire_to + 1 - hire_from)/(oneDay))); - Note the to and from should probably be other way around :)

Comment: Unfortunately that gave me the £ value of NaN. I had a play around with the code and this seems to work properly:   `var diffDays = Math.ceil(Math.abs((hire_to - hire_from + 1) /(oneDay)));`

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect what you found. In theory there is little difference between the two. I'd be interested to see what hire_to and hire_from values are in the case you get NaN. e.g. alert(hire_to); alert(hire_from); before the statement. Thanks.